Strange Occurrences When Using Titlesec and Section Title Begins with `L'
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,tocloft}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Sec. \arabic{section}.}


% % %  To center section number atop centered title text.
\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\sffamily\large\bfseries}
  {\filcenter\thesection}
  {1.00ex}
  {\justifycenter}

\newcommand{\justifycenter}[1]{%
  \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
  \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil
  #1%
}

%\renewcommand*\cftchapnumwidth{2em}
\renewcommand*\cftsecnumwidth{4em}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

%\tableofcontents

\LARGE
\section{This is Section I}
\vskip 10pt
\section{Likewise, This is Section II}
\end{document}

Strange Output:

Why---When the first letter of the section title is L---does the L get dropped and the title lose its centering? How may I correct this?

Both fil and fill are valid TeX glue "words", so 2fil #1 becomes 2fil l when argument #1 is the letter "l". Use some \relax to finish the glue expressions:
\newcommand{\justifycenter}[1]{%
  \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax
  \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil\relax
  \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil\relax
  #1%
}

By using \setlength\leftskip{0pt plus 1fil} you no longer have to remember this corner case of TeX syntax (although I personally prefer the simplicity of \leftskip=0pt plus 1fil\relax; it's up to you).

Thank you. That seems to do the trick.

you could also note that the fact the toc isn't affected is a clue here: you know the argument is being parsed correctly, so whatever eats it is specific to the formatting code.

TeX primitives are fun, aren't they?
There is a reason why the LaTeX manual recommends \setlength.
What you get from your code in the specific case is
\justifycenter{Likewise, This is Section II}

that becomes, according to the definition
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil \rightskip=0pt plus -1fil \parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil Likewise, This is Section II

An infinite glue specification can be
<decimal number> fil
<decimal number> fill
<decimal number> filll
but fil and l are separate keywords. So typing one of
2fill
2fil l
is completely equivalent. And TeX doesn't distinguish between uppercase or lowercase in keywords. So
\parfillskip=0pt plus 2fil L

is a perfectly good glue specification. Blame Knuth, if you wish, who probably found it more efficient to have such separate keywords instead of fil fill and filll (likely in order to parse them more quickly).
Define \justifycenter in the correct way, namely
\newcommand{\justifycenter}[1]{%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{0pt plus 1fil}%
  \setlength{\rightskip}{0pt plus -1fil}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 2fil}%
  #1%
}

and you'll be on track.
Oh, and do use \vspace with blank lines before and below. Otherwise something like
\vskip 10pt
Plus, I'm feelin' groovy.

might reserve some surprise:
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   I
<to be read again>
                   '
l.2 Plus, I'
            m feelin' groovy.

Exercise: why doesn't TeX stop at the comma but at I?
